# Inserting and combining data between 2 table

Tags: plsql

We have a table **students** with ID,NAME,SURNAME. We want have another table (created) **students_2** with ID1,NAME1,SURNAME1.

Starting from table students, i want to fill data in the second table in the following way : I want to have in the second table combinations of names ( example : NAME,SURNAME1; NAME1,SURNAME1). Moreover, i want to generate combination of names.

How can  I do that ? I tried something like :

```
INSERT INTO students_2 (ID1,NAME1,SURNAME1) SELECT ID,NAME,NAME from students;
```

But it's not correct cause I don't generate combinations, just inserting . A solution is appreciated, but mainly i need ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like

```
INSERT INTO students2(NAME, VALUE) FROM 
SELECT s1.name, s2.value from students1 s1 cross join students1 s2
```

This will do Cartesian product , and will get a NxN rows with combinations